# ReactJS - Can not map whilst using onChange event

Tags: reactjs, mapping, onchange

I have `category select` dropdown and at this moment, I'm using virtual data with an array.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        search: '',
        categories: '',
        products: '',
        categories: ['Technology', 'Sport', 'Fashion', 'Clothes'],
    }
```

Then, I use mapping to iterate through it

```
 <div className="col-lg-4">
    <select id="categories" className="form-control">
      {
       this.state.categories.map((i, index) => <option key={index} value={i} >{i}</option>)
      }
    </select>
 </div>
```

This way it works. However, I want to change state depending on the selected category, but when I add `onChange={handleCategories}` to `select` I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.categories.map is not a function
```

By googling I noticed people usually have problems while trying to use mapping with objects (only works for array), however I couldn't find any links to my problem.

NOT WORKING:

```
<div className="col-lg-4">
   <select id="categories"  onChange={handleCategories}  className="form-control">
      {
        this.state.categories.map((i, index) => <option key={index}  >{i}</option>)
      }
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with code which is not working. How are you passing `onChange` function?

Comment: @Prakash updated

Comment: Does the error occur when you change the option? If yes then show `handleCategories` function.

Comment: I just got it few min ago, it was problem in a method, even thought I didn't understand why, but yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function to the instance using `this.handleCategories.bind(this)`, otherwise the function won't be aware of the state.categories

Comment: I binded  `this.handleCategories = this.handleCategories.bind(this)` like this, but anyways I located the exact place where the error is coming from, which was in method.

Comment: @Seinfeld are you saying you have solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to use `target.value`.